# SELECT COUNT(table.column) - for every month, giving a column per month

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a mysql table `cases` that looks like this:

```sql
person_id   reason            date
     01       abc     2021-11-23 00:00:00
     02       def     2021-11-23 00:00:00
     01       ghi     2021-12-03 00:00:00
     03       abc     2021-10-23 00:00:00
     01       def     2021-11-23 00:00:00
```

And I want to count the number of `reason`'s for every reason, for every month, having a column for every month, lets say for the last 12 months:

```sql
reason   2021/01  2021/02  2021/03  2021/04   ...
  abc      125      255      111      189     ...
  def      364      846      215      792     ...
  ghi      251      700      251      105     ...
```

What I got so far is this SELECT, it returns a endless number of rows and I don't know where to go from here:

```sql
SELECT MONTH(cases.date) , cases.reason, COUNT(cases.reason) 
FROM cases
WHERE cases.date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
GROUP BY MONTH(cases.date), cases.reason
```

---

Based on Tim's Answer I built following sql SELECT, it's not perfect but good enough for me:

```sql
SELECT
    reason,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 11 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS "11 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 10 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS "10 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL  9 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "9 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL  8 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "8 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL  7 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "7 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL  6 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "6 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL  5 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "5 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL  4 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "4 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL  3 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "3 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL  2 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "2 months ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL  1 MONTH), '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "1 month ago",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(),                              '%Y-%m') THEN 1 END) AS  "this month"
FROM cases
GROUP BY reason;
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS you use.

Comment: Why do you want the date as a column name? That's a SQL Anti-Pattern. The SQL way of doing this is to have one column for the reason, one column for the month, and one column for the count; giving 36 *(3 reasons * 12 months)* rows of results.

Comment: @MatBailie It's an anti-pattern as a table design, but as a reporting requirement it might be common.

Comment: mysql. Exactly, I would need it for reports, I was doing it by hand so far and it took me forever.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The normalised structure also separates presentation responsibilities from the data layer, makes the query easier to utilise by further data processing layers in the future, is flexible to how many months are required and which particular date range, etc, etc. Having data (month name) in the column names is very much an anti-pattern, making it harder to reuse, adapt, maintain, etc. (Even having `month1`, `month2`, etc, would be 'less' of an anti-pattern.)

Comment: Is it going to be exactly last 12 months or last n months where n is unknown?

Comment: Doesn't really matter that much, exactly 12 months would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a wide format output, and so should be using a pivot query:

```
SELECT
    reason,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2021-01' THEN 1 END) AS "2021/01",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2021-02' THEN 1 END) AS "2021/02",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2021-03' THEN 1 END) AS "2021/03",
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') = '2021-04' THEN 1 END) AS "2021/04"
FROM cases
GROUP BY reason;
```